# How to retrieve Authenticated Adwords User 10 Digit Account ID?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

This is the SCOPE I'm using while authenticating the User.

```
 SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"];
```

I'm able to authenticate the user using oAuth2.0 and saving the refresh_token and access_token.

How do I get the Authenticated User's Ad Account Id which is in the below format.

Ad Words Account ID : XXX-XXX-XXXX

Comment: Can someone comment why they are downvoting? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: What client id are you referring to exactly?  Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DaImTo edited.

Comment: I am sorry i am still not seeing anything in your edit to tell me what exactly it is you think a users client id is.

Comment: @DalmTo Not Client ID, it is Ad words 10 Digit Account ID

Comment: @DaImTo I have updated my question, could you please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a call to the CustomerService and get a list of Google Ads accounts that the authorised user has access to. If they only have access to one account that's all you'll see.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview